# how to evaluate variables within character string in C

Tags: c

Sorry for asking a basic question but how would I do the following to get the pid to be part of the file name like this:

```
int pid;
int fOUT;enter code here
pid=getpid();
// TRYING TO EVALUATE HERE
char* filename=printf("hello-world-%i.txt", pid); # obviously wrong 
//char* filename="here.txt";
fOUT= open (filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_SYNC);
```

thx for any help

Comment: Use [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), or preferably: `snprintf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `snprintf` and allocated buffer for this:

```
#include <limits.h>

// ...

char filename[PATH_MAX];
snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "hello-world-%d.txt", pid);
```

About `PATH-MAX`: [Where is PATH_MAX defined in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449241/where-is-path-max-defined-in-linux) and [this link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html).

Comment: @timpone See the edit - it should be the `maximum number of bytes in a pathname, including the terminating null character.` Also, see this link, if it is important for you: http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd/porting/guidelines.html.

Comment: great, thx for answer. works like a charm; need to wait a few

Comment: @timpone - _what should MAX_PATH be?_ typically defined as 260.  Always safer to use macro rather than hard-coding a value though.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf), or perhaps more conveniently (but less portably) [`asprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf).