# relying on PATH_MAX can cause overflow

Tags: c, linux, security, x86, buffer-overflow

as you know `PATH_MAX` is value use to indicate the max size of an environment variable (in this case `PATH` variable), but it's not topically the case in most cases take a look at this code that is used to copy the environment variable into an array of size `PATH_MAX`

```
  char env[PATH_MAX]; 
  strcpy(path, getenv("PATH"));
```

if you can see it can overflow so easily, one would say use `strncpy` so you can avoid overflow, but if you use it and  the `PATH` is large then `MAX_PATH` we will not be able to get the `PATH` env variable complete and that make me thinking, how I could get the PATH env variable with the assumption that should be no overflow nor loss of data

Comment: *as you know PATH_MAX is value use to indicate the max size of an environment variable*  [`PATH_MAX` isn't even guaranteed to exist](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html): "A definition of one of the symbolic constants in the following list *shall be omitted* from the <limits.h> header on specific implementations where the corresponding value is equal to or greater than the stated minimum, but where the value can vary depending on the file to which it is applied. The actual value supported for a specific pathname shall be provided by the pathconf() function."

Answer (score 7):

In general *if* you need to copy an unknown-length string at all, see the [`string_copying(7)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/string_copying.7.html): `strncpy` is usually the wrong choice, not 0-terminating long strings, and wasting time zeroing out to the end of the size limit for short strings.  There aren't any good choices in portable ISO C, other than `strlen` + manual check + `memcpy` and even that's not great since it reads the input twice.  The `string_copying` man page shows an implementation of a non-standardized `stpecpy` in terms of POSIX.2008 [`memccpy`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memccpy.3.html) with a stop-character of `0`, adding a manual terminator in case the input didn't fit.

Or use **`strdup`** to malloc a copy.

Or for single filenames, you can sometimes use POSIX `openat(dirfd, basename, O_RDONLY);` instead of concatenating a filename onto a directory, especially if you already had the directory open to read its entries.

---

> as you know `PATH_MAX` is value use to indicate the max size of an environment variable (in this case `PATH` variable)

#### No it isn't; it has nothing to do with `$PATH` or the environment!!

**It's the max length of a single filesystem pathname**.  e.g. `/foo/bar/verylongdirectoryname/x/y.txt` is guaranteed to be at most `PATH_MAX` in length.  Or else you might not be able to read it with an absolute path and have to instead chdir into that tree and use a relative path.

The `PATH` environment is just a flat string like any other env var; the kernel doesn't clip them to a fixed length.  Or certainly not capped at `PATH_MAX`.

> how I could get the PATH env variable with the assumption that should be no overflow nor loss of data

**Uh, you already have it with `getenv("PATH")`**.  That returns a pointer to the existing string in your process's memory space.  It's effectively in static storage; you don't need to copy it and future calls to `getenv` won't break the pointer.  (On Linux, env vars are on the stack above argv at process startup.  The CRT startup code that runs before anything has moved the stack pointer stores a pointer to them in global `envp` where `getenv` can find it later.)

If you want to *copy* the buffer for an env var so you can lengthen it, or modify it without changing the original, **the easiest option is [`strdup(3)` from `<string.h>`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) to malloc a copy.**  (POSIX 2008, and before that BSD, GNU C, and various other systems before that).  Or `strndup` to set a limit on the number of bytes to copy.

GNU C even has a version based on alloca, not malloc, in case you want a cheaper automatic-storage temporary.

---

#### `PATH_MAX`

**`PATH_MAX` is relevant for example in POSIX functions like [`getwd(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html)** where you provide a buffer but no length limit.  (But really you should use `char *getcwd(char *buf, size_t size)` instead; see the same link as `getwd`.  The man page also says:

> Note that on some systems, `PATH_MAX`
> may not be a compile-time constant; furthermore, its value may depend
> on the filesystem, see pathconf(3).

---

On my current Linux system (x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux, kernel 6.7, glibc 2.38-8), `PATH_MAX` is 4096, and apparently [has been this way for a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449241/where-is-path-max-defined-in-linux), although other OSes might have a smaller limit.  `struct dirent` member  `char  d_name[256]; /* Null-terminated filename */` (see `readdir(3)`) makes 255 (plus terminating `0`) an upper limit on the length of any *one* component of a path. This is `NAME_MAX`.  ([Glibc docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Limits-for-Files.html) say glibc itself doesn't enforce this limit on some systems, but the kernel might.)

A path can involve multiple directory components, like `/foo/bar/../baz/file.txt`, and its total length has a limit mostly for sanity, making fixed-size buffers work.

And to give the kernel permission to reject super long paths instead of having to handle cases where a path uses huge amount of memory. 4096 is the smallest page size across architectures Linux supports, so if it has to allocate space to copy a path, it fits in one page.

System calls like `chdir(2)` or `open(2)` are allowed to fail on paths longer than `PATH_MAX` (`ENAMETOOLONG`):

> `ENAMETOOLONG`
> A pathname, or a component of a pathname, was too long.

[`readlink(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html) takes a buffer size so it doesn't need to limit the length of the link target; it only mentions ENAMETOOLONG as a possible error from the path you supply, not the link name.

The POSIX spec doesn't *require* errors for `open()` on a long path, so an OS could define a smaller `PATH_MAX` but then still work for longer paths when possible.  But Linux's choice of 4096 seems to be a hard limit, with system calls like `open` and `chdir` failing with `ENAMETOOLONG` according to `strace`.

I tested by making some nested directories with long names by repeatedly moving a directory tree into a new directory so I could create a deep tree without ever using a pathname much longer than one component, and without `cd`ing into it. (GNU `rm -r` has no problem removing this directory tree, recursing with `fstatat` and `unlinkat` so the only paths it has to use are bare filenames.  If it ran out of file descriptors while recursing, you could pick apart this tree the same way I built it, [as in this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/667062/removing-an-apparently-infinitely-recursive-folder/667736#667736) about cleaning up a mess.)

```
mkdir x
 # Then repeat multiple times with up-arrow or a loop
mv x y; mkdir x; mv y x/zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz/
```

`ls -lR` eventually fails with "File name too long" on a path that's 4164 bytes long.

You can `cd` into that subdirectory in multiple steps, not all at once, such that `/bin/pwd | wc` shows it's a 5701-byte path (including newline instead of a terminating 0)

`ls -l /proc/self/cwd` has `readlink()` fail with `ENAMETOOLONG`, which should only happen when the kernel doesn't like the path.  If the link target string is too long for the buffer size user-space tried with initially, it silently truncates and user-space can try again.  But that's not happening, it returns an error.  Presumably because the kernel is unwilling to even invent a string to copy from that's longer than `PATH_MAX`.

GNU `/bin/pwd` tries `getcwd(buf, 4096)` which fails with `ENAMETOOLONG`.  It falls back to following `..` parent-directory entries and presumably matching the inode numbers to figure out which directory it was in.  (It starts by `stat`ing `.` and `/`.)  Apparently that's part of glibc's `getcwd` library function: I tried a C program that calls `getcwd(buf, sizeof(buf))` with `char buf[16384];`.  `strace` shows it tries that large size with a `getcwd` system call but gets `ENAMETOOLONG`, then does the same recursing up towards `/` that GNU `/bin/pwd` did.

Comment: @alk: the version of `getcwd` that doesn't take a buffer-size arg really is called `getwd`.  That is not a typo.  (I didn't know it existed either until looking for functions/syscalls with pathname outputs)

Comment: Hu! I am sorry, I was sloppy enough to just only check the spelling of the link you placed. :}

Answer (score 3):

Avoid assuming $PATH is defined or has limited length is the solution to your question and use a generic code like the one below.

```
char *path = NULL; 
  const char *temp = getenv("PATH");
  if (temp != NULL) {
    path = (char*) malloc(strlen(temp) + 1);
    if (path == NULL) {
      /* Handle error condition */
    } else {
      strcpy(path, temp);
    }
    /* Use path */
  }
```

Comment: POSIX 2008 added `strdup(3)` which mallocs a copy of a string for you (and it's been available on Linux for longer than that).  No need to write your own if you're using other POSIX functions.

Comment: @PeterCordes [C23 (*cough cough*) also adds `strdup()`](https://www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html#7.26.2.6)