# Getting system's max allowed path length in c

Tags: c, file, limit, filepath, ansi-c

How can I determine the maximum file path length allowed in the system my program is running on?
Is it in `limits.h`? because I didn't find it there.

Comment: Answer is compiler dependent.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica gcc ANSI C 90

Comment: [Where is PATH_MAX defined in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56385296/24103599) may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be NAME_MAX defined in `<limits.h>`

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html

Comment: It says that this is an implementation - defined constant

Comment: yeah usually it's on Linux system, not sure if it's also the same for Windows or MacOS

Comment: @avivgood2 Yes, implementation-defined is a good as it gets. It means the implementation must provide a document stating the value (and limits.h contents may be enough for that). NAME_MAX is not constant across the universe, as say, the speed of light. :-)