# Unable to build qtdeclarative (cross-compiling Qt5 for Raspberry Pi zero W): Error ‘PATH_MAX’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, linux, qt, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I have successfully cross-compiled qtbase for Raspberry Pi 0 W (by following  https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS) , but I'm unable to build the sub-module QtDeclarative for adding QML support.
With Qt5.15.0 I'm getting the following error :

```
/qtdeclarative/src/3rdparty/masm/wtf/OSAllocatorPosix.cpp:86:14: error: ‘PATH_MAX’ was not declared in this scope
     char buf[PATH_MAX];
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: It seems that `PATH_MAX` is a preprocessor, so you can define it like : `#define PATH_MAX 256`

Comment: @BattleTested, thanks for the suggestion. But why am I getting this error ? Is it related to cross-compiler toolchain ? I though ```PATH_MAX``` was already declared in `#include <linux/limits.h>` accrding to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449241/where-is-path-max-defined-in-linux. And why 256 ?

Comment: Take a look at the solution of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449241/where-is-path-max-defined-in-linux