# how to build gcc 11 cross compiler for jetson nano (arm64)

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm following [this](https://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/) guide but when I try to build the c++ library I get the following fatal error.

```
../../../../gcc-11.1.0/libsanitizer/asan/asan_linux.cpp: In function ‘void __asan::AsanCheckIncompatibleRT()’:
../../../../gcc-11.1.0/libsanitizer/asan/asan_linux.cpp:199:21: error: ‘PATH_MAX’ was not declared in this scope
  199 |       char filename[PATH_MAX];
      |                     ^~~~~~~~
../../../../gcc-11.1.0/libsanitizer/asan/asan_linux.cpp:200:35: error: ‘filename’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘rename’?
  200 |       MemoryMappedSegment segment(filename, sizeof(filename));
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~
      |
```

Comment: you need to include linux/limits.h. [Where is PATH_MAX defined in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9449241/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is PATH\_MAX defined in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449241/where-is-path-max-defined-in-linux)

Comment: @phuclv the file in question includes limits.h. It appears the file is found as the preprocessor isn't complaining. I'm not sure how to effectively debug this.

Comment: no, the header isn't included because `error: ‘PATH_MAX’ was not declared in this scope` is thrown. No one can tell what the problem is because there isn't enough information. You must create a [mcve] and show it

Comment: @phuclv I can confirm the header was included and that it did not contain PATH_MAX. Defining this in the header made the compilation succeed. I am now in the middle of testing the compiler prior to writing up an answer.

Comment: I've had exactly the same issue with that guide myself. Editing `limits.h` to "fix" it seems... sketchy, did it actually work for you?

Comment: @c-x-berger The test programs i compiled seemed to work. However, I don't think my testing was adequate. I didn't end up using it in prod. 

If you can come up with something better please let me know

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in `libsanitizer/asan/asan_linux.cpp`. It seems to find the wrong `limits.h` file.
I was able to work around it by modifying `asan_linux.cpp` as follows.

```
-#include <limits.h>
+#include <linux/limits.h>
```